# Why does sp_send_dbmail keep sending email?

Tags: loops, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vb.net-2010

First of, The problem has been resolved by using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989354/sp-send-dbmail-keep-sending-email).

But that question has been resolved without knowing why does sp_send_dbmail keeps sending emails.

My scenario.

I have a procedure that would check an entire excel sheet and check for its content, if there is any error that is found on the excel sheet, a procedure will fire and send emails to the concerned persons.

During tests, the procedure worked perfectly. Sending only one mail per error. If the sheet has 5 errors, the system will send 5 emails regarding the said errors. This is critical because the errors here are high priority and should always be perfect.

Then I added a code, for the details. There is not sending of emails here, however, during the tests. I found out that my procedure is sending emails non stop. and if I haven't deleted the queued emails, 4,000+ additional emails might have been sent. Good thing I am just using the test server. Right now, I am checking what might have happened that caused the phenomenon. And what counter measure can I use?

I have to post a very long code for this one.

Ask me if you need any additional information.

```
'My Main procedure
    Sub CheckDataOfExcel(ByVal locs As String)

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Dim location As String
        Dim isData As Boolean = False
        Dim m_CountTo As Integer = 0
        'Progress Bar STEP
        Dim PBStep As Integer

        filename = ""
        globalloc = ""
        'Gets Files from Folders
        Dim counting As Integer = 0
        Dim csvcount As String() = Directory.GetFiles(locs, "*.xls")
        Dim ToUploadCSV As String



        For counting = 0 To csvcount.Count - 1
            CheckListofCSV.Clear()
            filename = ""

            location = csvcount(counting).ToString
            globalloc = location

            ToUploadCSV = Path.GetFileName(location).ToString
            Dim ListLines As New List(Of String)
            Dim ListLinesNEW As New List(Of String)


            'Read the file


            'If data is retrieved
            xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(location)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            'Use this code to read the data from EXCEL

            'Check if file is already uploaded
            If ShowExclUpld(xlWorkSheet.Cells(62, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(4, 2).value) <> "" Then
                 MsgBox("A file named " & ShowExclUpld(xlWorkSheet.Cells(62, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(4, 2).value) & " was uploaded containing similar data of " & ToUploadCSV & " please check.")

            Else




                'ROWS
                Dim i As Integer = 5
                'COLUMNS
                Dim col As Integer = 2
                'SAMPLING COUNT FROM EXCEL
                Dim SampQTYXcel As Integer = 0
                'below code to check data only
                Do While Len(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, col).value) > 0

                    '**DATA DETAILS**
                    'Loop starts here
                    'Product Property Sub Header
                    For i = 5 To 10

                        'Check Dimension Here
                        'If Spec is correct, do nothing.
                        'I think I should just return the list of all the PPF,Part number,Dimension that 
                        'Create procedure to check SPecs? then get the file name and file location
                        'along with the PPFNo, PartNo, and Dimension name

                        checkSpecData(xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, col).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(62, 2).value, _
                        ToUploadCSV, location, xlWorkSheet.Cells(6, col).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, col).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(8, col).value, i)

                        'Now I should get a flag to tell the system not to upload this filename anymore...


                    Next

                    'TASK:Create POKAYOKE for Sample Size Checking
                    '1) Encoded Sample Size my be within the upper and lower limit specification
                    '2) Encoded Sample Size encoded must be equal to the Sample Size requirement encode from the database

                    'Use these data for POKAYOKE regarding Specification upper and lower limits
                    Dim XLUprLmt As Decimal = xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, col).value
                    Dim XLLwrLmt As Decimal = xlWorkSheet.Cells(8, col).value

                    If ExlErrorFlag = ToUploadCSV Then
                        'Sample Data 10 onwards
                        Do While Len(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, col).value) > 0
                            SampQTYXcel = SampQTYXcel + 1

                            If xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, col).value > XLUprLmt Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, col).value < XLLwrLmt Then

                                MsgBox(createEmailMsgForSamplErr(SampQTYXcel, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, col).value))

                            End If



                            i = i + 1

                        Loop

                        'Excel data has more data than Database QTY then REPORT 
                        If SampQTYXcel > SamplQTY Then
                                  MsgBox("ERROR")
                        End If

                        'Add 1 to move to next column
                        col = col + 1
                        i = 5
                        SampQTYXcel = 0
                    End If
                Loop

                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

                xlWorkBook.Save()

            End If




            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange)
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
            xlWorkBook.Close()
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
            xlApp.Quit()
            releaseObject(xlApp)

            xlApp = Nothing
            xlWorkBook = Nothing
            xlWorkSheet = Nothing

            Cleanup()

        Next

    End Sub
```

The SP

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Alter procedure [dbo].[checkData]
@PartNo as nvarchar(20),
@DimName as nvarchar(20),
@PPFNo as nvarchar(20),
@FileName as nvarchar(20),
@FileLocation as nvarchar(150),
@SpectoTest as nvarchar(20),
@UprLmtToTest as nvarchar(10),
@LwrLmtToTest as nvarchar(10) ,
@flag as integer

as

begin
Declare @TheEmailBody as nvarchar(max)
if @flag = 5
    begin
        if cast(@SpectoTest as decimal(18,4)) <>  (select cast(specification as decimal(18,4)) from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName)

            begin

                set @TheEmailBody = '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Part Number         : '+@PartNo+      '
Dimension Name: '+@DimName+    '
PPF Number          : '+@PPFNo+       '
File Name               : '+@FileName+    '
File Location          : '+@FileLocation+'

Error: Different Specification

Specification from EXCEL: '+@SpectoTest+' 
Specification from DB: '+ (select specification from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName) +'

This is a system generated email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'


                    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @profile_name = 'SendSQLMail', 
                    @recipients = 'someone@somewhere.com', 
                    @subject = 'TEST', 
                    @body =  @TheEmailBody,
                    @body_format = 'text'

                    select @FileName
            end
    end


else if @flag = 9
    begin

        if cast(@UprLmtToTest as decimal(18,4)) <> (select cast(UpperLimit as decimal(18,4)) + cast(specification as decimal(18,4))  from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName)

            begin
set @TheEmailBody = '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Part Number         : '+@PartNo+      '
Dimension Name: '+@DimName+    '
PPF Number          : '+@PPFNo+       '
File Name               : '+@FileName+    '
File Location          : '+@FileLocation+'

Error: Different UpperLimit

UpperLimit from EXCEL: '+@UprLmtToTest+' 
UpperLimit from DB: '+ cast((select cast(UpperLimit as decimal(18,3)) + cast(specification as decimal(18,3)) from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName) as nvarchar(max)) +'

This is a system generated email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'

            exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'SendSQLMail', 
            @recipients = 'someone@somewhere.com', 
            @subject = 'TEST', 
            @body = @TheEmailBody , 
            @body_format = 'text'

            select @FileName

            end

    end


else if @flag = 10

    begin
        if cast(@LwrLmtToTest as decimal(18,4)) <> (select cast(Specification as decimal(18,4)) - cast(lowerlimit as decimal(18,4))  from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName)

            begin
set @TheEmailBody = '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Part Number         : '+@PartNo+      '
Dimension Name: '+@DimName+    '
PPF Number          : '+@PPFNo+       '
File Name               : '+@FileName+    '
File Location          : '+@FileLocation+'

Error: Different LowerLimit

LowerLimit from EXCEL: '+@LwrLmtToTest+' 
LowerLimit from DB: '+ cast((select cast(Specification as decimal(18,3)) - cast(lowerlimit as decimal(18,3)) from DimensionMaster where PartNo = @PartNo and DimensionName = @DimName) as nvarchar(max)) +'

This is a system generated email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
            exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'SendSQLMail', 
            @recipients = 'someone@somewhere.com', 
            @subject = 'TEST', 
            @body = @TheEmailBody, 
            @body_format = 'text'

            select @FileName

            end
    end


end
```

Comment: `1sp_send_dbmail` sends as many emails as you tell it to. If you changed the sendmail line to output to a file you would find it writing thousands of lines.

Comment: Having said that..... I don't see your SP called anywhere in your VBA code. At a glance this looks _really_ complicated and i'm sure it could be done in a more simple manner

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I can somehow send just one email if the system sees only one error... its kind of confusing, I thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this the function call that sends the email: `checkSpecData`? As posted, your code never calls any emailing function at all.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `checkSpecData` is actually a sub and it contains the stored procedure `checkData` I have not added the sub in this code. Sorry Sir. The emailing function is ` exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail `

Comment: Does `checkSpecData` have any logic? Because it runs 5 times for every excel column. It's hard to understand what is going here without data but I don't see any logic that selectively calls the sub

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid today, I did not received any multiple email sent to me, everything is perfectly well. I still dont know what happened, or how to resolve this. Thank you for your time.